# How to mock a parent class using Spock and Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have the following grails code in a domain object...

```
@Override
StatusEnum getStatus(Date activeDate) {
    StatusEnum returnVal = super.getStatus(activeDate)
    if(address.getStatus() == StatusEnum.ACTIVE){
        returnVal
    }
    else{
        return StatusEnum.INACTIVE
    }
}
```

I am trying to test this and I would like to do something like this...

```
def "Make sure a invalid account address is invalid"(){
    given:
    Address address = Spy(Address)
    address.getStatus() >> StatusEnum.INACTIVE
    Date dt = new Date()
    ((PerishableDomain)domain).getStatus(dt) >> StatusEnum.ACTIVE
    when:
    def status = domain.getStatus(dt)
    then:
    status == StatusEnum.INACTIVE

}
```

The problem is with `((PerishableDomain)domain).getStatus(dt) >> StatusEnum.ACTIVE` which is of course not working. Short of going away from the grails autowiring or using another testing framework such as Mockito?

**Clarify**

The above code is what I would like it to do but it doesn't work.

The method I want to mock is `super.getStatus(activeDate)` and I would like it to return true without calling the parent class.

Comment: What does that line signify? What is `PerishableDomain`?

Comment: PerishableDomain is the parent class. The line is how I would like it to work in a perfect world

Comment: Looks like you are mocking the method under test. Can you add Address and PerishableDomain classes?

Comment: Not really Address is just another domain class. It extends PerishableDomain as well. Both have getStatus methods, and the domain contains an address. I could greatly simplify this by just saying I want to mock super method.

Comment: Your test is completely wrong. Which is the class under test? Where is the "domain" defined/created?